# Help making a 205 LED lamp

Tags: circuit-design

I had the crazy idea of making a lamp for my soon-to-be-born son. It is a bunch of LEDs (about 205.. yes I know...) representing a picture. The LEDs vary slightly in voltage and current specs, but I don't need all of them to burn full power regardless. So I plan on going with the 'safe' limits that go for all LEDs which are 2,5V and 20mA.
I understand the concept of placing a resistor of 'n' Ohm to make sure to not burn out the LEDs. I also am aware of the concepts of parallel and series set-ups. But... (here it comes)... I am unsure how to hook up these lights and to what power source.
Going by the calculations I have seen, I either end up with a 512,5V (all in series) or 4,1A (all in parallel) power supply. So I reckon I need to split it up a bit in a combination of series and parallel, but this is where I'm stuck at. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Find a surplus 19V laptop supply and match LED strings with 1~3V drop on R. Good Red LEDs are usually 2.1~2.2V

Comment: 205 LEDs at 20mA each may be a lot brighter than you want.  Be prepared to increase the resistors to cut the current if the whole thing ends up dazzling.  LEDs function well at only a fraction of their rated maximum current.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My recommendation is that you go for a safe voltage as this effectively eliminates electric shock hazard concerns. 24 V would be a good choice and power supplies are plentiful.

You can now sort out your LEDs by type and group each type in a series string to make up about "20 V worth" of LEDs and calculate a series resistor to drop the remaining 4 V on each string. \$ R = \frac {V}{I} = \frac {4}{20m} = 200 \ \Omega \$. I've chosen 4 V as a balance between having enough resistance to control the current adequately versus wasting power as heat in the resistors. You can adjust to suit the maths but don't go too low.

Then parallel each string and connect to your 24 V supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbOeRu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Series-parallel arrangement for 24 V supply.*

---

> If I were to work with 22,5 V worth of LEDs (so 1,5 V remaining on each string) it would amount to a 75 ohm resistor, correct?

Ideally, for driving LEDs you want a current source. An ideal current source has an infinite output impedance - i.e., a very high series resistance. The lower you make your series resistor the poorer a current source it makes. Let's do the calculations for your 9 LEDs, 22.5 V, with a 75 Ω series resistor per string and work out what happens if the headroom changes by 1 V either due to a variation in the LEDs V<sub>F</sub> or a variation in the PSU output voltage.

- Nominal headroom: 1.5 V. \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {1.5}{75} = 20\ \mathrm{mA} \$.
- 1 V low, 0.5 V. \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {0.5}{75} = 6.6\ \mathrm{mA} \$ (-66%).
- 1 V high, 2.5 V. \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {2.5}{75} = 33\ \mathrm{mA} \$ (+66%).

Now let's reduce your string of nine LEDs to eight with a nominal voltage of 20 V and a series resistor of 200 Ω and repeat the calculations.

- Nominal headroom: 4 V. \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {4}{200} = 20\ \mathrm{mA} \$.
- 1 V low, 3 V. \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {3}{200} = 15\ \mathrm{mA} \$ (-25%).
- 1 V high, 5 V. \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {5}{200} = 25\ \mathrm{mA} \$ (+25%).

You should be able to see from all this that the 200 Ω / 8 LED solution will regulate the current better if there is variation of the LED V<sub>F</sub> due to manufacture or temperature or variation in the supply voltage. This is the background to my recommendation in the original answer.

Comment: If I were to work with 22,5V worth of LEDs (so 1,5V remaining on each string) it would amount to a 75 Ohm resistor, correct? Which then would lead me to have 23 string of 9 LEDs in total (or well, the last one would have less and need a higher Ohm resistor). I was thinking of maybe making the different LED strings (sorted by colour, so amount of strings might still vary) dimmable as to make sure the white LEDs don't outshine the orange ones etc. Would that be as simple as putting a potentiometer at the start of the string? Thanks for the very detailed answer, learning as I go along :D

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Using 24 V and 26 strings with 8 LEDs each is a very good solution. There should be no LEDs with different colour in the same string. To balance the intensity of a colours used, the 200 Ohm resistors may be modified. If some LEDs are too bright, increase the resistors for all strings with that colour. But if you want to use potentiometers instead of resistors, they should be rated for the current and the resulting power. 200 Ohm at 4 V and 20 mA would require at least a rating for more than 0.08 W.

Comment: @Uwe, I've seen many assume that the power rating is independent of the wiper position so I would modify your last sentence to, "The power rating of the pot should be > I²R, so for 20 mA and a 1k pot it would be 0.4 W even if only part of the track is being used."

Comment: That is true and important, for 200 Ohm and 20 mA power is only 0.08 W, but for 1 k and 20 mA power is 0.4 W. 5 times the resistance will result in 5 times the power at constant current.

Comment: @Transistor I have used your detailed calculations to calculate the resistors to use for my other colours. I decided to up the amount of LEDs by one to have a nice and even number of white LEDs. Otherwise I would end up with one really high resistor for either 1 or 2 LEDs. Now I have 200 Ohm for the orange, 300 Ohm for yellow and 440 Ohm for the White ones. I still might have to put in something to dim the intensity, but I'll first have to see how this looks. Thanks a lot for all the help.